# Multiple RKRelationshipMapping with same toKeyPath

Tags: ios, mapping, restkit

I have a problem using multiple RKRelationshipMappings with same toKeyPath (destinationKeyPath).
I have had success with using one RKRelationshipMapping to one toKeyPath but I'm unable to attach a second RKRelationshipMappings with the same toKeyPath.

**Code with one RKRelationshipMapping that works:**

```
RKObjectMapping *someObjectRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[someObjectRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"prop1" : @"prop_1", @"prop2" : @"prop_2"}]; 

RKObjectMapping *firstSubObjectMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[firstSubObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"subProp1" : @"sub_prop1", @"subProp2" : @"sub_prop2"}];

[someObjectRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"prop3"
                                                                                         toKeyPath:@"prop_3"
                                                                                       withMapping:firstSubObjectMapping];
```

However, if i want to add another RKRelationshipMapping to "someObjectRequestMapping" with the same toKeyPath ("prop_3") the RestKit fails with error:

*'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to add mapping for keyPath invites_attributes, one already exists...'*

**Code with two RKRelationshipMappings that fails:**

```
RKObjectMapping *someObjectRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[someObjectRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"prop1" : @"prop_1", @"prop2" : @"prop_2"}]; 

RKObjectMapping *firstSubObjectMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[firstSubObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"subProp1" : @"sub_prop1", @"subProp2" : @"sub_prop2"}];

RKObjectMapping *secondSubObjectMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[secondSubObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"subProp2" : @"sub_prop2", @"subProp3" : @"sub_prop3"}];

[someObjectRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"prop3"
                                                                                         toKeyPath:@"prop_3"
                                                                                       withMapping:firstSubObjectMapping];

[someObjectRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"prop4"
                                                                                         toKeyPath:@"prop_3"
                                                                                       withMapping:secondSubObjectMapping];
```

The mapping is used in RKRequestDescriptor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Damir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear, RestKit will not allow ambiguity so you can only have one mapping per key path.

Usually if this was for a response descriptor you would use a dynamic mapping to determine which relationship mapping was appropriate. For a request descriptor you can do something similar yourself where you analyse the object to be sent and decide which mapping is appropriate. This does mean having 2 different mappings and choosing between them manually. This could also be done using multiple `RKObjectManager`s, each configured with a different set of mappings.

Comment: thank you for your response. Yes, I saw dynamic mapping which is used in response descriptors. I was thinking about what you said, analysing the object to be sent and deciding which mapping to take. That part is not a problem, but I was wondering how to "attach" that mapping to my destination keypath ("prop_3" in example above) and add it root mapping (someObjectRequestMapping)...

Comment: Different object managers could be easiest. Or add and remove the descriptors.

Comment: Ok, but how to "merge" those object managers to perform a single PUT or any other REST action? All REST methods are instance methods of RKObjectManager...

Comment: Choose the appropriate instance to use, no merging. That's what the check are for, which mapping (manager) is the correct one for the object to be posted.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying, but my problem is not that (at least I think). The problem is that I have some API endpoint which accepts JSON request with some array property. I have 2 different arrays of custom NSObject class objects, which I want to map to mentioned JSON array property. Both arrays contain objects of the same type but first array should be mapped differently than the second one. Array property should contain all objects in final request JSON.

Comment: Merging the two arrays would need to be done as post processing after RestKit had done all of the mapping work.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer. It would be great if you would come up with some solution for merging the two mapped arrays.

Comment: Are you able to change what the server expects? That would be easier than trying to merge 2 different parts of JSON text. An alternate easier option may be a subclass so you can set each mapping for a different class...